# Reviewing a suggested edit "inline" does not dismiss the popup

Tags: bug, design, suggested-edits, popups

Whenever I review a suggested edit "inline" (i.e., by clicking the <kbd>Edit(1)</kbd> button as opposed to in the review queue), the popup doesn't get closed and the review buttons are not even disabled; only the view of the edit is "dimmed". At first, I thought maybe the action wasn't submitted but re-submitting triggers an error.

Here's a demo:

[image: A gif demonstrating the behavior described above]

I've been noticing this on Stack Overflow. But I just [confirmed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXs36.gif) that it happens here on MSE too. The same thing also happens if "Approve" is chosen instead of "Reject" (except when that leads to the edit being immediately approved, which refreshes the page anyway).

Comment: This was already "fixed": https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411847/error-encountered-when-approving-a-suggested-edit